# Facebook API Not returning all of a public pages wall posts with access token

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the PHP Facebook API but it doesn't return all of the wall posts from my public page with a valid access token - and I can't figure out what's so special about those posts. They were all made by me, the page owner - Any ideas?

FYI the posts that arent working contain:
https://www.facebook.com/events/205819312854732/
https://www.facebook.com/events/207820205995213/

PHP is:
$wall = $validFacebookObject->api('/184196778359304/feed?access_token=".$validToken','GET');

Comment: We need more details - code? Ideally link to these posts/posts which are working

Comment: please write here your coding which you use to get posts data

Answer (score 1):

You can't get ALL posts in one call. If you look at the bottom of the response you'll see:

```
"paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/184196778359304/feed?format=json&limit=25&since=1334425968&__previous=1",
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/184196778359304/feed?format=json&limit=25&until=1331389779"
  }
```

You can either use the "next" and "previous" URL's to parse through the posts, or include "limit" and "offset" parameters in your calls (ie: graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/feed?limit=100&offset=500&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN will get posts 501 to 600)

Comment: I figured it out, it's because the posts were about events that weren't public! I'm not allowed to put this as the real answer yet...

Comment: No bother, if this is all that was causing the issue just answer yourself / mark as community wiki and approve in 2 days :)